# How to get first entry with a value from an hierarchical setting structure?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a couple of tables. One table with Groups:

```
[ID] - [ParentGroupID]
1    - NULL
2      1
3      1
4      2
```

And another with settings

```
[Setting] - [GroupId] - [Value]
Title       1           Hello
Title       2           World
```

Now I'd like to get **"Hello"** back if I'd query the Title for Group 3 
And I'd like to get **"World"** back if I'd query the Title for Group 4 (And not "Hello" as well)

Is there any way to efficiently do this in MSSQL? At the moment I am resolving this recursively in code. But I was hoping that SQL could solve this problem for me.

Comment: There is no recursion needed for this.

Comment: So it seems. I was thinking more complicated than I had to. Thanks for the help everyone

Comment: If the Groups table can have any depth, and the settings can also be applied at any level, you will need recursion. Fortunately, since SQL Server 2005 you can use a Recursive Common Table Expression for those cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem we've encountered multiple times in our company. This would work for any case, including when the settings can be set only at some levels and not others (see SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/16af0/1/0 :

```
With GroupSettings(group_id, parent_group_id, value, current_level)
As
(
    Select g.id as group_id, g.parent_id, s.value, 0 As current_Level
    From Groups As g
    Join Settings As s On s.group_id = g.id
    Where g.parent_id Is Null
    Union All
    Select g.id, g.parent_id, Coalesce((Select value From Settings s Where s.group_id=g.id), gs.value), current_level+1
    From GroupSettings as gs
    Join Groups As g On g.parent_id = gs.group_id
)

Select *
From GroupSettings
Where group_id=4
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't knoww the SQL Server syntax but something like the following?

```
SELECT settings.value
  FROM settings
  JOIN groups ON settings.groupid = groups.parentgroupid
 WHERE settings.setting = 'Title'
   AND groups.id = 3
```

Comment: Wait, this will not work. Because if I then look for groupID 1. I still expect the Hello to be returned there too.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following is what you are seeking. See the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/02033/7)

```
SELECT vALUE FROM
Groups g inner join Settings s 
ON g.ParentGroupId = s.GroupID
WHERE g.ID = 3 -- will return Hello,], set ID = 4 will return World
```

Comment: Wait, this will not work. Because if I then look for groupID 1. I still expect the Hello to be returned there too.